# Programmatically check in OS X if there is an active ethernet connection?

Tags: macos, cocoa, connection, ethernet

How can I know my mac is connect to network by ethernet. Is there any method in cocoa which checks it?

I flung a wifi connection check, but no ethernet connection check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:-
First import this below framework and then write the below code

```
#include <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h> 

    NSString *pingHost = @"abc.apple.com"
    SCNetworkConnectionFlags flags = 0;
    if (pingHost && [pingHost length] > 0) {
        flags = 0;
        BOOL found = NO;
        SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachabilityRef = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(kCFAllocatorDefault, [pingHost UTF8String]);
        if (reachabilityRef) {
            found = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachabilityRef, &flags)
            &&  (flags & kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)
            && !(flags & kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired);
            CFRelease(reachabilityRef);
            reachabilityRef = NULL;
        }
        if (found) {                
            NSLog(@"Connection established");
        }
        if (!found) {
            NSLog(@"Connection not established");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3597085/195893) answer, you need to add the SystemConfiguration framework to your project